# How to work with a function in vector form

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

I would like to use Mathematica to compute the X and Y elements of the vector on the left (below) for various t values and put result in a column vector form? I used Mathematica's palette to write the eqn below in vector form.

[image]

Comment: Would something like this work? `v = Function[t, {1, 2} 100 2^t + {3, 0} 3 0.9^t];` You could then use e.g. `v[3]` to get values.

Comment: `{x[t_], y[t_]} = {1, 2} 100 2^t + {3, 0} 3 0.9^t;
x[t]`

Comment: Mathematica does not distinguish between row and column vectors. `XY[t_] = 100*2^t*{1, 2} + 3*(0.09)^t*{3, 0}; X[t_] = XY[t][[1]]; 
Y[t_] = XY[t][[2]];`

Comment: All: thank you very much!! Bob: That looks correct ... prg